Good book about PDE on manifold
I have already learn Riemannian Geometry, and know a littile PDE. I want to know which book is suitable for me to learn the PDE on manifold ?
For example, I saw  that  on closed manifold, $\Delta u= f$ has solution iff  $f$ has mean value zero. I can feel it is right, but I don't know how to prove it. I need this knowledge. Thanks.

I recommend:

Thierry Aubin  "Some Nonlinear Problems in Riemannian Geometry"
Emmanuel Hebey "Nonlinear Analysis on Manifolds: Sobolev Spaces and Inequalities".


The first one is a really good collection of problems to start with! Good one!

We have
$$
\int_M vf=\int_M v\Delta u=\int_M u \Delta v
$$
for all $v \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and setting $v=1$ yields the desired result. In order to prove this, you need to prove Greens identity on manifolds. They follow from the divergence/Stokes theorem.
Depending on your background, I think the book by Jost "Riemannian Geometry and Geometric Analysis" is a good starting point, especially the chapters about harmonic maps and their respective prerequisites. It will also help you to prove the above identity with ease. It has a nice summary on Sobolev spaces in the appendix.
Since you have said that (Riemannian) geometry is already your strong suite, I recommend reading some basic modern PDE theory. The book of Evans "Partial Differential equations" does a great job, and I would recommend focusing on second order elliptic and parabolic equations, as well as the chapter on the calculus of variations. Further topics, such as basic gradient flows/semigroup theory (since you tagged ricci-flow) is also covered in the book.
In my personal opinion, geometric PDEs are quite unique and each of them requires a different technique to tackle them, there is no single monograph that I am aware of. Even the "most-studied" equation
$$
\Delta u=0
$$
for $u: \Sigma_1 \to \Sigma_2$ for maps between Riemann surfaces(!) has no uniform approach (spoiler: it boils down to whether $\Sigma_2=S^2$ is the two-sphere or not). The "Partial Differential Equations" book series by Michael Taylor has some more accessible material on PDEs on manifolds as well.
In general, however, I would recommend to pick a problem you like after you have learned the basics and go from there. Study what is required to understand this particular problem.

To be clearer for OP: your first paragraph only shows the “only if” direction of the statement. The converse is obviously the more difficult and requires the following two usual steps: formulate the problem in a weak sense (in function space obtained by the completion of $E={f\in C^{\infty}(M),:, \int_Mf,dV=0}$ relative to the $H^1$ Sobolev norm) in order to get a weak-solution (using Riesz-representation or Lax-Milgram). Then, in a second step, invoke/prove elliptic regularity (via a-priori estimates and Sobolev embedding)  for which we can reduce to the familiar case of $\Bbb{R}^n$.

fortunately for this specific problem, I found a short enough writeup online which goes through all these details: Poisson Equation on Closed Manifolds.

That is perfect! Try to understand the details and the next PDE on a manifold you will try to understand will become a lot easier.

Thanks for your advice, and I've been hesitant to read Evans's book.
